# Gas Sensor Library for Proteus

Tags: arduino-uno

Does any one know how to use Gas Sensor module in Proteus. I wanna use Gas Sensor but I am unable to find it in Proteus. So, does anyone know any way of adding Gas Sensor Library for Proteus software. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [Gas Sensor Library for Proteus](http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2016/05/gas-sensor-library-proteus.html), so I thought to share it here so that others can also get benefit out of it. They have also posted the complete method of How to use this Gas Sensor Library and have also given an example to download.

Thanks.